# Multiple sites one one physical windows server

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

What I have:

- Domain, registered by GoDaddy (lets imagine that it named mysite.com)
- AWS EC2 server instance, Windows Server 2012 R2
- Static IP address provided by Amazon Elastic IP and assigned to this server
- Installed Jira on port 7010
- Installed Confluence on port 7020

What I need:

- Make Jira application accessible on `http://jira.mysite.com`
- Make Confluence application accessible on `http://confluence.mysite.com`
- Make ability to route any additional application on my server from any port to `http://subdomain.mysite.com` (this is why I can't use single instance of tomcat on port 80, because I don't know what sites I will needed to add in future)
- Ability to install SSL certificate to all of above

What I should not need to use:

- Any payable service (for example AWS load balancer)

How can I setup it? Maybe with IIS, apache, nginx or any another tool? Or maybe I don't understand something and it can be performed by another way?

P.S. I am not administrator, my specialization is software developer, so, please describe it as for very-very beginner :)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Server Fault!

Subdomains are only capable of directing to an IP, not specific ports. Instead you'd need

```
 http://confluence.example.com:7020
```

or even

```
 http://example.com:7020
```

to be able to access Confluence/JIRA on the same server. Having subdomains to reference each would only work if you hosted both applications on port 80 on two seperate servers.

I don't understand your third requirement, but as per my point above, all of your subdomains are only capable of pointing to IPs, not ports. You'd have to specify the port on the end of the domain.

SSL certificates are one per subdomain/domain. Meaning unless you purchase whats called a Wildcard SSL certificate, you will have to buy one for each subdomain. With the multiple single domain certificates or the wildcard certificate though it should be trivial to install with instructions obtained from your provider!

Comment: Is I know it is possible to host multiple sites on one ip (same server). Need to some king of automatic tunneling which depends on host name in http-request.

Comment: Yep you can host as many different sites on the same server. You'd specify the difference in the virtual hosts files.

Comment: How can I setup it?